# Dictionary<string, int> does not have value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have problem with put values into Dictionary.

My Code:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> cnDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();

Dictionary<string, int> cn = new Dictionary<string,int>();

cn.Add("DynamicPanel_1", 0);
cn.Add("DynamicPanel_3", 1);
cn.Add("DynamicPanel_4", 0);
this.cnDict.Add("DynamicPanel_2", cn);

cn.Clear();

cn.Add("DynamicPanel2", 1);
cn.Add("DynamicPanel3", 0);
this.cnDict.Add("DynamicPanel1", cn);
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> pos in cnDict["DynamicPanel_2"])
{
    MessageBox.Show("DynamicPanel_2 has values: "+ pos.Key + " ----> " + pos.Value.ToString()); ;
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pos in cnDict["DynamicPanel_1"])
{
    MessageBox.Show("DynamicPanel_1 has values: " + pos.Key + " ----> " + pos.Value.ToString()); ;
}
```

This code display wrong messages:

- DynsmicPanel_2 has values: DynamicPanel_2 ----> 1
- DynsmicPanel_2 has values: DynamicPanel_3 ----> 0
- DynsmicPanel_1 has values: DynamicPanel_2 ----> 1
- DynsmicPanel_1 has values: DynamicPanel_3 ----> 0

Should be:

- DynsmicPanel_2 has values: DynamicPanel_1 ----> 0
- DynsmicPanel_2 has values: DynamicPanel_3 ----> 1
- DynsmicPanel_2 has values: DynamicPanel_4 ----> 0
- DynsmicPanel_1 has values: DynamicPanel_2 ----> 1
- DynsmicPanel_1 has values: DynamicPanel_3 ----> 0

What I do wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: You add same `cn` object twice to `cnDict` dictionary. Create new object: replace `cn.Clear();` by `cn = new Dictionary<string,int>();`

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov: You should put that as an answer. I was just about to put pretty much exactly that but since you posted first I don't want to ninja your answer. ;-)

Comment: @ Ulugbek Umirov  -  I cant do it because: Error 1 A local variable named 'cn' is already defined in this scope

Comment: @mtoy Don't declare it again. Just do `cn = new Dictionary<string,int>();` instead of `cn.Clear();`.

Comment: @mtoy Noticed how Ulugbek's code states `cn = ..`, not `Dictionary<string, int> cn = ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. It works. Beers for you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add same `cn` object twice to `cnDict` dictionary. Create new object: replace `cn.Clear();` by `cn = new Dictionary<string,int>();`